# Proof the following statement

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n\geq2$ if there exist some $b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $b^{n-1}\not\equiv1\pmod{n}$ and $\gcd(b, n) = 1$, then$$\left|\{1\leq a\leq n-1 : a^{n-1}\not\equiv1\pmod{n}\}\right|>\frac{n-1}{2}$$ where $|X|$ is the number of elements in $X$.

I though of finding pairs $x_1,x_2$ such that $x_1$ is in the given set and $x_2$ is not and and in the end there will be no pairs and the remaining numbers will be in the set but was not able to get anywhere with the approach. Can someone help.

**Solution :** We can partition the set $S = \{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ as follows
$$X = \{x\in S: x^{n-1}\not\equiv1\pmod n, \gcd(x,n)=1\}$$
$$Y = \{y\in S: y^{n-1}\equiv1\pmod n,\gcd(y,n) = 1\}$$
$$Z = \{z\in S:\gcd(z,n)\neq1\}$$

Then clearly we have
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{matrix}
    X\cap Y = \phi, & X\cap Z = \phi, & Z\cap Y = \phi, & X\cap Y\cap Z = \phi
    \end{matrix}
\end{equation*}

So we have \begin{equation*}
    |X\cup Y\cup Z|=|X|+|Y|+|Z|+|X\cap Y|+|Z\cap Y|+|X\cap Z|-|X\cap Y\cap Z|
\end{equation*}

$$\implies n - 1 = |X|+|Y|+|Z|$$

`...(1)`

For any $z\in Z$ let $\gcd(z,n) = d > 1$

Then we will have $d|n$ and $d|z$

Or $d|n$ and $z = d\cdot w$ for some $w\in\mathbb{Z}$.

If $z^{n-1}\equiv1\pmod n$ then $n|z^{n-1}-1$

$$\implies d|z^{n-1}-1\implies d|(d\cdot w)^{n-1}-1$$ $$\implies d|-1$$
which is not possible hence we have $$z^{n-1}\not\equiv1\pmod n$$ for any $z\in Z$.

Now, by definition of $X$ we have $b\in X$ or $X\neq\phi$.

Consider the case when $n$ is prime then using Fermat's Little Theorem we can see that \begin{equation*}
    \begin{matrix}
    X = \phi, & Y = S, & Z=\phi
    \end{matrix}
\end{equation*}
but $X\neq\phi$ so $n$ cannot be a prime or $n$ is a composite number then we must have $$|Z|\geq1$$

`...(2)`

For $y\in Y$ then
$$y^{n-1}\equiv1\pmod n$$
\begin{equation*}
    \implies b^{n-1}\cdot y^{n-1}\equiv b^{n-1}\pmod n
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \implies b^{n-1}\cdot y^{n-1}\not\equiv 1\pmod n
\end{equation*}
`(as b is a element of X)`
\begin{equation*}
    \implies (b\cdot y)^{n-1}\not\equiv1\pmod n
\end{equation*}

Also $\gcd(b,n)=1$ and $\gcd(y,n)=1$ so $\gcd(b\cdot y)=1$.

Hence $y\cdot b\in X$

Now we will prove that for every element in $Y$ we will have a unique element in $X$ as follows:

If $y_1b\equiv y_2b\pmod n$, then $y_1\equiv y_2\pmod n$ as $\gcd(b,n)=1$. So we can conclude that for distinct elements $y_1,y_2\in Y$ we will have $y_1b$ and $y_2b$ in $X$ and are distinct so we must have $$|Y|\leq |X|$$

Now using (2) we have $$|Y|<|X|+|Z|$$
$$\implies |Y|+|Y|<|X|+|Y|+|Z|$$`(using (1))`

$$\implies 2|Y|<n-1\implies|Y|<\frac{n-1}{2}$$

or using (1) again we have
$$|X|+|Y|>\frac{n-1}{2}$$

Now observe that $A = X\cup Y = \{a\in S:a^{n-1}\not\equiv1\pmod n\}$ then

$$|A|=|X\cup Y|=|X|+|Y|-|X\cap Y|=|X|+|Y|-0$$

$$\implies|A|>\frac{n-1}{2}$$

$$\square$$

Comment: Just a suggestion: why not draw inferences from Fermat's Little Theorem to solve this problem? For instance, if $n$ is prime, then all of the integers from $1$ to $n-1$ are not in the set, aren't they? There you get $|X|=0$ (where $X$ is the set seen in the statement to be proved). [I did this thinking in a hurry so as to shut the computer down, so perhaps I may have gone erroneous... if someone's reading this comment, please verify my claim].

Comment: Yes your claim is correct but if n is prime then there will not exist such a b and the only conclusion we can make is that n is composite.

Comment: so you've proved the statement? Congrats! I'm sorry that I noticed this message a little late. Being a school student in the last year of schooling and also since COVID's almost out of the global scene, I'm mostly offline, attending offline classes at school. But yeah, I really appreciate you (I wish I had a creative mind at math like yours! I sit with my mouth open in the entrance classes when the teacher gives us some JEE Advanced type problem... I wish I could learn to be a better hard-worker and a creative thinker...)

Comment: I am a math major and currently in my second year, so I do these kinds of things on a daily basis and furthermore the other students are better than me at these kind of things in fact I got a hint from one of my classmate that led to the solution.
Thanks anyway.